# Titus 2:13 Savior Jesus Christ as title or appositive

Tags: greek, christology, titus

In Titus 1:3, among other passages, we find “σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ“ used as a singular title “Our Savior God/God our Savior”.

However in Titus 2:13 we find “σωτῆρος ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ” is generally rendered as an appositive, “Our Savior, Jesus Christ”. Is it possible this phrase is a singular title “Our Savior Jesus Christ” rather than the appositive?

Comment: _of our great God and Saviour Jesus Christ,_ Young's Literal, Titus 2:13.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Granville Sharp's Rule indicate that “God” and “Savior” share a referent in Titus 2:13 and 2 Peter 1:1?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/does-granville-sharps-rule-indicate-that-god-and-savior-share-a-referent-in)

Comment: I think you should consult the famous "sharp rule" about this; this is called TSKS by Wallace in his "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics".

Comment: This has nothing to do with GSR. That's a distraction from the real message here. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63948/did-paul-treat-god-and-jesus-as-one-person-in-titus-213/63949?r=SearchResults&s=1|61.5979#63949

Comment: Plz don't mark this as duplicate or vote to close it. I reviewed it as Leave open. This is not related to Sharp rule, but he is asking whether "Saviour Jesus Christ" could be a single title like asking whether "Christ" is the surname of Jesus. Is Saviour Jesus to be taken as Mr. Savior-Jesus or Jesus, the saviour? King Agrippa is Agrippa, the King, or King is his surname?

Comment: The question is asking, can this be saying : God AND Jesus, the saviour? Instead of God and Saviour, Jesus; where Jesus is both God and Saviour. This doesn't look like a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Any_mouse. Could you explain in the question what you think the significance of the difference would be? Perhaps that will help to keep the question open.

Answer (score 3):

By way of clarification, "God", "Savior", "Lord", "Christ" are all titles.  The only proper name in Titus 2:13 is "Jesus".

The grammar of these two texts are VERY clear:

- Titus 1:3 - τοῦ Σωτῆρος ἡμῶν Θεοῦ = The Savior of us, God.  In this case "God" is in apposition to "our Savior"
- Titus 2:13 - τοῦ μεγάλου Θεοῦ καὶ Σωτῆρος ἡμῶν Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ = the great God and Savior of us, Jesus Christ.  In this case, "Jesus Christ" is in apposition to "our great God and Savior".

Thus, God has the title, "Savior" which agree with Isa Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21, 1 Tim 1:1, etc.

Further, Jesus Christ has the title "God and Savior" as well and agree with:

> 2 Tim 1:10 - And now He has revealed this grace through the appearing
> of our Savior, Christ Jesus, who has abolished death and illuminated
> the way to life and immortality through the gospel,

See also 2 Peter 1:1, 3:18, Titus 1:4, etc.

Titus 2:13 is a good example of what Daniel Wallace in his book, "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics" 9GGBB) calls the TSKS rule (sometimes also called the Granville Sharp Rule).  See page 270ff of GGBB.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have missed the entire point of Titus 2:13 as too many seem to do. "the appearing of *the glory* of our great God..." This is not making Jesus God, he is the *glory of God the Savior* and that is what will be appearing in the person of Jesus.

Comment: @steveowen - grammarians beg to differ.

Comment: Agreed and up-voted. The literal text reads _the great God and Saviour of us_ . . . The possessive 'of us' refers to both 'great God' and 'Saviour'. The glory is both of 'the great God' and also of 'the Saviour'. The Greek can mean nothing other than that one Person is in view and one glory is in view. But only those who are in the secret of Deity can also understand that since 'God' is involved, there is a necessity (by unity) of a broader involvement. The grammar is abundantly clear : but also so is the unity of divinity.

Comment: I am familiar with the two common views of this passage: 1 - Jesus is our great God and Savior. 2 - Jesus is the glory of our great God and Savior. However, if “Our Savior Jesus Christ” is a singular title rather than an appositive of “Our Savior” with “Jesus Christ”, that would disqualify GS rule, because it doesn’t apply when proper names make up the TSKS construct.

Comment: @Any_mouse - you have misunderstood - "God" and "Savior" are the two titles to which the TSKS rule applies.  "Jesus Christ" is in apposition to the one person, "God and Savior".

Comment: @Dottard thank you. This actually answers my exact question. I don’t think I misunderstood, because this is what I was trying to ask. Unless I also misunderstand your response here. So you are saying it is required that “Jesus Christ” be in apposition to something? There is no way that “Savior Jesus Christ” is viewed as a singular substantive? For example, you find βασιλεῦ Ἀγρίππα treated as a single title “king Agrippa”, not appositive “king, Agrippa”. But with a hypothetical TSKS “the consulate and king Agrippa”. It would need to be “the consulate and king, Agrippa”?

Comment: @Any_mouse - which verse are you referring to about Agrippa?  In any case, "king" is a title and "Agrippa" is a proper name.  "Jesus" is a proper name and "Christ" is a title.

Comment: @steveowen - If Jesus is the glory of God who will appear, then you are suggesting that Titus 2:13 says something like, "the appearing of Jesus [the glory of God our savior] and Jesus Christ.  That is, Titus 2:13 is saying we look forward to the appearing of Jesus and Jesus.  Does this make sense? - hardly!

Comment: Jesus is the person - glory is his descriptor.  The Son is the radiance of God's glory and the representation of His nature Heb 1:3 T 2:13 makes perfect sense when you stop trying to read in all kinds of dogma.

Comment: @steveowen I agree this is a likely reading. Especially with the Ἐπεφάνη of grace in 2:11 paralleling the ἐπιφάνειαν of glory 2:13, as well as σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ throughout Titus referring to the Father. However, I have heard that the distance between δόξης and Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ weakens the case for a shared referent. Also, I’ve heard the claim that μεγάλου is required to refer to Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ, though I’m not sure why.

Comment: @Any_mouse nuance of any verse aside, the overwhelming narrative always, but for a handful of so-called proof-texts, clearly distinguishes Jesus from God. Why would this be any different?

Answer (score 0):

**God our Savior - Our Savior God**
Titus 1:3:

> and at the proper time manifested in his word through the preaching with which I have been entrusted by the command of **God our Savior** (ESV)
> `ἐφανέρωσεν δὲ καιροῖς ἰδίοις τὸν λόγον αὐτοῦ ἐν κηρύγματι ὃ ἐπιστεύθην ἐγὼ κατ᾽ ἐπιταγὴν τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ`
>
> but He revealed His word *in His* own times, in *the* proclamation which I was entrusted-*with* according-to the command *of* **our Savior God** (DLNT, also Darby)

Paul was entrusted by command from τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ; literally ***the** Savior of us, God*, usually rendered as *God our Savior* because *God* is taken to be in apposition to *our Savior*. Two translations understand the article places emphasis on Savior meaning, *our Savior God*.

**The LXX**
The combination of God and Savior occurs 13 times in the LXX, often with one or more articles:

Deuteronomy 32:15 (LXX-NETS)

> And Iakob ate and was filled, and the beloved one kicked. He grew fat; he became heavy; he became broad! And he abandoned God who made him, and he departed from God his savior.
> `καὶ ἔφαγεν Ιακωβ καὶ ἐνεπλήσθη καὶ ἀπελάκτισεν ὁ ἠγαπημένος ἐλιπάνθη ἐπαχύνθη ἐπλατύνθη καὶ ἐγκατέλιπεν θεὸν τὸν ποιήσαντα αὐτὸν καὶ ἀπέστη ἀπὸ θεοῦ σωτῆρος αὐτοῦ`

Psalm 24:5 [23:5]

> He it is that will receive blessing from the Lord and mercy from his divine savior.
> `οὗτος λήμψεται εὐλογίαν παρὰ κυρίου καὶ ἐλεημοσύνην παρὰ θεοῦ σωτῆρος αὐτοῦ`

Psalm 25:5 [24:5]:

> Guide me to your truth, and teach me, because you are God, my savior, and for you I waited all day long.
> `ὁδήγησόν με ἐπὶ τὴν ἀλήθειάν σου καὶ δίδαξόν με ὅτι σὺ εἶ ὁ θεὸς ὁ σωτήρ μου καὶ σὲ ὑπέμεινα ὅλην τὴν ἡμέραν`

Psalm 62:2 [61:3]:

> Indeed, he is my God and my Savior, my supporter; I shall be shaken no more.
> `καὶ γὰρ αὐτὸς θεός μου καὶ σωτήρ μου ἀντιλήμπτωρ μου οὐ μὴ σαλευθῶ ἐπὶ πλεῖον`

Psalm 62:6[61:7]:

> Because he is my God and my Savior, my supporter, I shall never be a fugitive.
> `ὅτι αὐτὸς θεός μου καὶ σωτήρ μου ἀντιλήμπτωρ μου οὐ μὴ μεταναστεύσω`

Psalm 65:5 [64:6]

> Hearken to us, O God, our savior, the hope of all the ends of the earth, and in the sea far away
> `ἐπάκουσον ἡμῶν ὁ θεὸς ὁ σωτὴρ ἡμῶν ἡ ἐλπὶς πάντων τῶν περάτων τῆς γῆς καὶ ἐν θαλάσσῃ μακράν`

Psalm 79:9 [78:9]

> Help us, O God our savior; for the sake of the glory of your name, O Lord, rescue us and atone for our sins, for the sake of your name.
> `βοήθησον ἡμῖν ὁ θεὸς ὁ σωτὴρ ἡμῶν ἕνεκα τῆς δόξης τοῦ ὀνόματός σου κύριε ῥῦσαι ἡμᾶς καὶ ἱλάσθητι ταῖς ἁμαρτίαις ἡμῶν ἕνεκα τοῦ ὀνόματός σου`

Psalm 95:1 [94:1]

> A laudation. Of an Ode. Pertaining to Dauid. O come, let us rejoice in the Lord; let us make a joyful noise to God our savior!
> `αἶνος ᾠδῆς τῷ Δαυιδ δεῦτε ἀγαλλιασώμεθα τῷ κυρίῳ ἀλαλάξωμεν τῷ θεῷ τῷ σωτῆρι ἡμῶν`

Isaiah 12:2

> Behold, the Lord is my God, my savior; I will trust in him and will not be afraid because the Lord is my glory and my praise, and he has become my salvation.
> `ἰδοὺ ὁ θεός μου σωτήρ μου κύριος πεποιθὼς ἔσομαι ἐπ᾽ αὐτῷ καὶ σωθήσομαι ἐν αὐτῷ καὶ οὐ φοβηθήσομαι διότι ἡ δόξα μου καὶ ἡ αἴνεσίς μου κύριος καὶ ἐγένετό μοι εἰς σωτηρίαν`

Isaiah 17:10

> Because you have abandoned God your savior and have not remembered the Lord our helper, therefore you will plant an unfaithful plant and an unfaithful seed.
> `διότι κατέλιπες τὸν θεὸν τὸν σωτῆρά σου καὶ κυρίου τοῦ βοηθοῦ σου οὐκ ἐμνήσθης διὰ τοῦτο φυτεύσεις φύτευμα ἄπιστον καὶ σπέρμα ἄπιστον`

Isaiah 45:15

> For you are God, and we did not know it, O God of Israel, Savior.
> `σὺ γὰρ εἶ θεός καὶ οὐκ ᾔδειμεν ὁ θεὸς τοῦ Ισραηλ σωτήρ`

Micah 7:7

> But as for me, I will look to the Lord; I will wait for God my Savior; my God will hear me.
> `ἐγὼ δὲ ἐπὶ τὸν κύριον ἐπιβλέψομαι ὑπομενῶ ἐπὶ τῷ θεῷ τῷ σωτῆρί μου εἰσακούσεταί μου ὁ θεός μου`

Habakkuk 3:18

> But i will exult in the Lord; I will rejoice in God my savior.
> `ἐγὼ δὲ ἐν τῷ κυρίῳ ἀγαλλιάσομαι χαρήσομαι ἐπὶ τῷ θεῷ τῷ σωτῆρί μου`

Word order does not dictate the sense, but Savior is never placed before God and the article is never used only with Savior. There are four different compositions, none of which mean God is not also Savior. The most frequent composition is article-God-article-Savior-pronoun. It is apparent Paul chose to compose a distinct phrase.

**The Title, *Our Savior***
Paul's phrase can be understood as placing God in apposition, *God our Savior*. Yet, Paul deviated from the LXX by placing Savior first; something he repeated.

Titus 2:10 (DLNT)

> not pilfering, but demonstrating all good faith, in order that they may adorn the teaching of our Savior God in all things.
> `μὴ νοσφιζομένους ἀλλὰ πᾶσαν πίστιν ἐνδεικνυμένους ἀγαθήν ἵνα τὴν διδασκαλίαν τὴν τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ κοσμῶσιν ἐν πᾶσιν`

Titus 3:4 (DLNT):

> But when the kindness and love-for-mankind of our Savior God appeared
> `ὅτε δὲ ἡ χρηστότης καὶ ἡ φιλανθρωπία ἐπεφάνη τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ`

Based on repeated use, the term `τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν` appears to be a title, *our Savior*.

***Our Savior, Christ Jesus***
Immediately after the first use, Paul follows with this statement:

Titus 1:4:

> *to* Titus, genuine child according-to *a* common faith: Grace and peace from God *the* Father and Christ Jesus our Savior
> `Τίτῳ γνησίῳ τέκνῳ κατὰ κοινὴν πίστιν χάρις καὶ εἰρήνη ἀπὸ θεοῦ πατρὸς καὶ Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν`

Paul places Father in apposition to God and Our Savior in apposition to Christ Jesus. Father is written without the article; our Savior is written with the article. With respect to the phrase `Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν`, Paul follows the practice of the LXX by placing Savior second. However, unlike the LXX Paul **unnecessarily** includes the article with Savior. *Christ Jesus our Savior* should be `Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν`. The consistent use of the article even when it is not necessary affirms `τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν` is a title. In the case of vese 4, the best understanding is *our Savior Christ Jesus*.

**The Great God and Our Savior**
Titus 2:13 (DRA):

> Looking for the blessed hope and coming of the glory of the great God and our Saviour Jesus Christ
> `προσδεχόμενοι τὴν μακαρίαν ἐλπίδα καὶ ἐπιφάνειαν τῆς δόξης τοῦ μεγάλου θεοῦ καὶ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ`

Many scholars understand the phrase using what is known as Sharp's Rule. This states a writer who intends to describe a single person with two attributes will compose the phrase as TSKS ["the"-substantive-and/*kai*-substantive]. Leading with an article indicates the writer wants the reader to understand there is just one, having both attributes. So, ***the** great God and our Savior, Jesus Christ*.

The rule is named after Granville Sharp. Because he demonstrated how this principle identifies the deity of Christ, it is mistakenly categorized as a rule to read the original text for that purpose. However, Paul and every New Testament writer routinely used this principle.

> `εὐλογητὸς ὁ θεὸς καὶ πατὴρ` means *blessed be **the** God and Father*, not ***the** God and **the** Father*

Sharp's work led to a rule by his name because he correctly identified TSKS is the principle a writer uses to describe one with two attributes such as God and Father, `ὁ θεὸς καὶ πατὴρ`.

**Summary**
Here are the five Savior phrases Paul composed:

> Titus 1:3 `τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ`
> Titus 1:4 `Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν`
> Titus 2:10 `τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ`
> Titus 2:13 `τοῦ μεγάλου θεοῦ καὶ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ`
> Titus 3:4 `τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ`

When 2:13 is understood with the TSKS principle, the force of the article continues to the second substantive, *our Savior*. Additionally it is clear this is Paul's intention, since the previous identification of Christ and Savior placed *our Savior* in apposition to Christ. That means, the actual phrase Paul composed in 2:13, purposely deviated from the earlier identification Christ Jesus as our Savior.

The change from `Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν` to `σωτῆρος ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ` avoids an accepted exception to the TSKS principle. When a substantive is a name the principle should not be applied. Likewise, the unnecessary addition of *great* to describe God accomplishes two things. First, it prevents the claim the article is intended for God only; `τοῦ μεγάλου θεοῦ` is significantly different from `τοῦ θεοῦ`. Second, it shows both substantives were intentionally described with two terms: great God - Our Savior Jesus Christ.

**Conclusion**
*Our Savior* is used as a title throughout this letter.

Paul has used the title to show it applies to God (1:3, 2:10, and 3:4) and to Christ (1:4, 2:13).

Answer (score -2):

My answer to this question was copied and pasted from https://jesusnotyhwh.blogspot.com/2016/11/titus-213.html

Titus 2:13 - The Great God
"Looking for the blessed hope and the appearing of the glory of our great God and Savior, Christ Jesus." -- Titus 2:13, New American Standard

This scripture is often listed, sometimes paralleled with scriptures such as Isaiah 45:21, as proof that Jesus is Jehovah God Most High., the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. Does this scripture actually give proof of such?

First of all, there is nothing in the scripture about three persons in one God, nor is there any scripture that identifies Jesus as being the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob; such ideas have to imagined using the spirit of human imagination, formed into dogma, then the assumed dogma has to be added to, and read into the scripture.

Titus 2:13
prosdechomenoi teen makarian elpida kai epiphaneian
AWAITING THE HAPPY HOPE AND MANIFESTATION
4327 3588 3107 1680 2532 2015
tees doxees tou megalou theou kai swteeros heemwn
OF THE GLORY OF THE GREAT GOD AND OF SAVIOR OF US
3588 1391 3588 3173 2316 2532 4990 1473_8
christou ieesou
OF CHRIST JESUS,
5547 2424 -- Westcott & Hort Transliterated Interlinear

This scripture can possibly be translated different ways, depending upon the translator's understanding of what is being said, or bias. Albert Barnes, although he contends that Jesus is being called the great God in Titus 2:13, does state: "It is uncertain whether these words should be read together thus, 'the glory of our Lord Jesus Christ, the great God and our Savior,' or separately, as of the Father and the Son, 'the glory of the great God, and of our Savior, the Lord Jesus Christ.'" Since, Jesus is definitely NOT the "one God" of whom are all (1 Corinthians 8:6), the correct procedure should be to view Titus 2:13 from that perspective. The Greek form for "God" above is transliterated as "THEOU", a form of "THEOS."

Nevertheless, according to Hebraic usage, the words from which forms of the Greek word for Theos are translated from the Hebrew also are used in a more general sense of Might, Strength. The Christian certainly receives his strength through Jesus. Of course, Jesus is the One of Power sent by the only true God, Jehovah, who gives Jesus his power, and Jesus is the savior sent by the only true God, Jehovah. Jesus is theos -- deity, a powerful one -- and is therefore true theos in a secondary sense, but not in the sense of being the only true Supreme Being, the Source of all might. In the Bible, only the God and Father of Jesus is spoken of as having the attribute of being "one God" of whom are all. (1 Corinthians 8:6) Even as the saints are called *theoi*, so it would be proper to call Jesus *theos*, as the one given power and authority by Jehovah. -- John 10:34,35; 17:1,3 -- See also Psalm 82.

Additionally, "the Lord Jesus Christ" could be referring to the word "glory". Jesus will indeed, in effect, come as "the glory" of his God and Father (Ephesians 1:3), as he is the "sun of righteousness." -- Malachi 4:2, and Jesus comes in the glory of his God and Father.  -- Matthew 16:27; Mark 8:38; Luke 9:27.

Nevertheless, we highly doubt that it was Paul's intent to speak of Jesus as the "great God."

We present below several translations of Titus 2:13 that render this verse in various ways:

"while we wait for the blessed hope and the manifestation of the glory of our great God and Savior, Jesus Christ". -- New Revised Standard Version

"Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the great God, and our Savior Jesus Christ;" -- The Webster Bible

"Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the great God and our Saviour Jesus Christ;" -- King James Version

looking for the blessed hope and appearing of the glory (Footnote: 1) of the great God and our Saviour Jesus Christ; -- Footnote: (1) Or of our great God and Saviour ) -- American Standard Version

Looking for the blessed hope and coming of the glory of the great God and our Savior Jesus Christ, -- Douay-Rheims

expecting the blessed hope; namely, the appearing of the glory of the great God, and of our Saviour Jesus Christ; -- Living Oracles

looking for the blessed hope, and the manifestation of the glory of the great God, and our Life-giver, Jesus the Messiah; -- Murdock

Prepared to welcome the happy hope and forthshining of the glory of the great God and our Saviour Christ Jesus, -- Rotherham

Regarding Titus 2:13 Paul S. L. Johnson states
Tit. 2:13 is also alleged as a proof of the trinity by some, who to find in their thought, render the words in question as follows: 'the appearing of the glory of our Great God and Savior Jesus Christ.' This rendering is not preferred by a majority of learned trinitarians, though it is a possible rendering. Rendered as in the A.V., A.R.V. text, and a majority of modern translations, not our Lord Jesus but the Father is here called God. The fact that, properly translated, Paul never calls Jesus God, but always contrasts Him as Lord with the Father as God, is decisive on which is the right translation. Again, the connection (v. 11) naturally suggests that the bright shining is of the Father and of the Son. St. Paul's use of language, calling the Father God over 500 times and never once calling Jesus God, must rule in this case as to which is the right translation. Force, too, is added to our view by the words [A.R.V.] *the glory of the Great* God." -- Ephiphany Studies in the Scriptures, Volume 1, God, pages 525,526. -- (One should note that this was written back in the 1930s, before many of the modern translators had sought to render this verse to read in favor of the trinitarian view.)
**We should also note that Titus 3:6 definitely shows that it is the Father who shed the holy spirit "through Jesus Christ our Savior." And we also can look at Titus 1:4: "to Titus, my true child according to a common faith: Grace, mercy, and peace from God, the Father, and the Lord, Jesus Christ, our Savior." (World English Bible translation) Here Paul clearly distinguishes between God the Father and the Lord Jesus. "God" in Titus 1:4 does not mean three persons, it means one person, and Jesus is not included as "God". This gives further evidence that Titus 2:13 does not reflect a triune God, or that Jesus is the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob.**

The revealing (epiphaneia) spoken of in Titus 2:13 probably refers to the time when the glory of Jehovah is revealed to all flesh, not to Jesus' appearance (Phaneroo) at his first advent, as spoken of in 1 Timothy 3:16. -- Isaiah 40:5; 11:9; Psalm 72:19.

The millennial kingdom of Christ will not only be the time of revealing of the glory of God and Christ, but also of the seed of Abraham, the chosen sons of God of this age. -- Romans 8:19; Galatians 3:26,29; 1 John 3:2.

Additionally, **Titus 2:14 adds "who gave himself for us to redeem us from all iniquity and to purify for himself a people of his own who are zealous for good deeds." This scripture shows that the man Jesus -- not God -- "gave" himself. Who did the man, Jesus Christ, 'give himself' to? To God himself! (1 Timothy 2:5,6; Hebrews 9:24; 10:10)** Thus a little reasoning indicates that Jesus is not the same as the unipersonal God to whom he gave himself.

See also:
Barry Hardy's comments at:
https://groups.google.com/groups?selm=19980706.191409.3222.0.barryhardy%40juno.com

But someone argues: The rule of Greek grammar that applies here is that if there are two nouns separated by the word "kai" (and), then if each noun has an article with it, they refer to different things. But if only one of them has an article, they refer to the same thing. In these cases, we have two nouns ("God" and "Saviour"), separated by the word "kai", with only one of them having an article. According to this "rule" of Greek grammar, these two words refer to the same person.

What is often called the rules of grammar are not inherently rules of a language, but are made so by men who create such rules based on study of general usage. Such "rules" usually always have exceptions, which is also true of this "rule", as seen in the Septuagint of Proverbs 24:21. Granville Sharp is attributed to formulating the above rule which he presented in a book in 1798, long after Paul and Peter had written their letters. It would be an assumption to think that Paul had such a rule in mind when he wrote the above to Titus.

Nevertheless, according to Sharp's rule: "When the copulative kai connects two nouns of the same case, [viz. nouns (either substantive or adjective, or participles) of personal description, respecting office, dignity, affinity, or connexion, and attributes, properties, or qualities, good or ill], if the article o, or any of its cases, precedes the first of the said nouns or participles, and is not repeated before the second noun or participle, the latter always relates to the same person that is expressed or described by the first noun or participle: i.e. it denotes a farther description of the first-named person." (Sharp, Remarks on the Uses of the Definitive Article, 3.) **Sharp's sole purpose in his study was to promote the idea that Jesus is Jehovah, so he did not include "things" in his rule, thus he narrows his study to substantives (that is., nouns, substantival adjectives, substantival participles) of personal description, not those which referred to things, and only in the singular, not the plural. He states that "there is no exception or instance of the like mode of expression, that I know of, which necessarily requires a construction different from what is here laid down, EXCEPT the nouns be proper names, or in the plural number; in which case there are many exceptions ." In other words, he found a way to exclude or provide exceptions to his rule so as to make it appear that the rule would support the idea that several passages are saying that Jesus is Jehovah God Almighty.**

Conversely, Sharp claimed that if two nouns of the same case are connected by a "kai" (and) and the article (the) is used with both nouns, they refer to different persons or things. If only the first noun has the article, the second noun refers to the same person or thing referred to in the first. -- Curtis Vaughn, and Virtus Gideon, A Greek Grammar of the New Testament" (Nashville: Broadman Press, 1979), p. 83.}" But Sharp came up with exceptions to this rule so that it would not apply to John 20:28.

Since writing the above, we have been given some quotes of various scholars concerning Titus 2:13, that we believe would be beneficial here:
The repetition of the art[icle] was not strictly necessary to ensure that the items be considered separately." -- A Grammar of the New Testament Greek, (Volume # was not supplied), by James Hope Moulton and Nigel Turner.
Unfortunately, at this period of Greek we cannot be sure that such a rule [Sharp's] is really decisive. -- Grammatical Insights into the New Testament, 1965, by Nigel Turner
It will probably never be possible, either in reference to profane literature or to the NT, to bring down to rigid rules which have no exception,... -- A Grammar of the New Testament Greek, by Alexander Buttmann
The grammatical argument ... is too slender to bear much weight, especially when we take into consideration not only the general neglect of the article in these epistles but the omission of it before "Savior" in 1 Timothy 1:1; 4:10. -- The Expositor's Greek Testament, by N. J. D. White
Let us look at an interlinear of Titus 2:13:
prosdechomenoi teen makarian elpida kai epiphaneian
AWAITING THE HAPPY HOPE AND MANIFESTATION
4327 3588 3107 1680 2532 2015
tees doxees tou megalou theou kai swteeros heemwn
OF THE GLORY OF THE GREAT GOD AND OF SAVIOR OF US
3588 1391 3588 3173 2316 2532 4990 1473_8
christou ieesou
OF CHRIST JESUS,
5547 2424
Westcott & Hort Greek / English Interlinear
NEW TESTAMENT coded with Strong's numbers
(as obtained from the Bible Student's Library DVD)
It should be obvious from the above that the Greek structure here is highly complex. First we have an article before two nouns -- two things -- connected by kai for which the Christian is awaiting -- teen makarian elpida kai epiphaneian -- the happy hope and manifestation. It is apparent that in this verse that there are two things being waited for -- "hope" and "manifestation", although one article is present, both of which are related to "glory" that is to be manifested at that time -- the glory of the great God and our Savior, Jesus Christ. (Compare Romans 8:19,24,25) The manifestation is followed by a phrase describing what the manifestation is: "of the glory of the great God and of Savior of us, Jesus Christ." We again have an article used of the possessive; the article before glory is of the great God and Savior of us. Thus the "glory" is applied to two nouns, "God" and "Savior". It is speaking of the glory of God and it is speaking of the glory of our Savior. As one reads this, we don't think anyone would see in this that the reference to the great God and the savior are speaking of one person, except that their minds had been preconditioned to think of the expression in such terms. We certainly don't think Paul was trying to structure his sentence in such a way to leave the impression that Jesus is God Almighty. Regardless of whether one would think that THEOS in Titus 2:13 is applied to Jesus or not, one would still have to call upon the spirit of human imagination to think that it means that Jesus is the Jehovah, the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. And, if one wishes to think of trinity regarding this verse, he still has to use the spirit of human imagination so to think that THEOS means the second alleged person of the alleged triune God, which God is never once mentioned in the Bible.

There is even more to this, for let us read the verses before:

Titus 2:11 For the grace of God that bringeth salvation hath appeared to all men,

Titus 2:12 Teaching us that, denying ungodliness and worldly lusts, we should live soberly, righteously, and godly, in this present world; -- King James Version.

Now we know that "grace" or "favor" did not make some physical appearing, but rather the knowledge through Christ concerning the grace of God appeared to all the men being spoken of, that is, Christians, both Gentile and Jew, teaching them how to live in this evil world while they awaited the happy hope and manifestation of the glory. Thus Paul is summing up the work of the first advent and the second advent, as to what is revealed at both events. The parallel between the advents is "grace" and "glory". The grace is of God through Christ. (Titus 1:3) The "glory" is of the great God and our Savior, the latter who is then identified as Jesus Christ. Thus the whole idea is the glory of our great God and the glory of our Savior, which glory we are awaiting the manifestation of.

As seen from Westcott & Hort's Interlinear, the Greek has the possessive *heemwn*, which appears after *swteeros*, which, according to the usual construction, would also demand an article before that which is possessed, that is, *swteeros*. There is no definite article before swteeros, so we go looking for a definite article earlier, which we find before *megalou theou*, "great God". Then this article is applied to both "great God" and "Savior." Since there is no separate article applied to Savior, some wish to conclude that one person is referred to as both God and Savior. Still, there we have no reason to think that this was Paul's intention, and there is certainly nothing definite in this conclusion. Sharp himself had to make exceptions to his rules in order to seemingly narrow them down for his purposes.

In view of the context, we do not believe that Paul here was constructing this sentence this way to show that Jesus is God Almighty, regardless of how one applies or makes exceptions for Sharp's rule in this verse. One still has to use the spirit of human imagination to think that it means that Jesus is Jehovah, and further use of the spirit of human imagination to think that it means one person of a triune Jehovah. It does appear more likely that he just wrote what seemed to him to be a way of saying that we are awaiting the appearance of both the glory of the great God and of our Lord Jesus. Nevertheless, even if Jesus is being called 'Great God", we should connect the phrase "Great God" here with the phrase with the more general Hebraic usage of such, that is, of Jesus as the Great Mighty One, rather than to call upon the spirit of human imagination so as to think that Paul was saying that Jesus is the Most High. This application would still not make Jesus into God Almighty, but as a Great One of Power, as made so by the Almighty Jehovah.

Then there is something else to consider concerning Titus 2:13 and Sharp's rules. As noted above, he provided exceptions to his rules if the nouns were proper nouns. Some argue that "God" and "Savior" in Titus 2:13 are semantic equivalents to such proper names, as titular names, and therefore Sharp's exception to his rule should apply to this verse.

Some claim that only Jehovah can be savior, and thus since Jesus is referred to as savior in Titus 2:13, that means that Jesus is Jehovah. Several scriptures show that besides (or apart from) Jehovah there is no savior. (Isaiah 43:11; 45:11; Hosea 13:4) None of these scriptures, however, say that Jehovah cannot sent someone who is not himself as a savior, for the Bible records many whom Jehovah sent as saviors to Israel as recorded in the Old Testament. These saviors whom Jehovah sent are besides (apart from) Jehovah since Jehovah sent them. -- Nehemiah 9:27.

Overall, actual proof is lacking in Titus 2:13 that Jesus is Jehovah. The arguments presented for such are questionable, to say the least. One has to first assume that Jesus is God Almighty, then read this into the scripture, and then say that this is proof, which is, in effect, circular reasoning. Without all the circular reasoning that has been imagined toward the verse, it is not that difficult to understand in harmony with the entire Bible.

Comment: You state that "Sharp's sole purpose in his study was to promote the idea that Jesus is" God, and devote much space to disagreeing with Sharp's rule of Greek grammar on this point. However, it could equally be said that your sole purpose in this answer is to promote the idea that Jesus is not God. As one point cancels the other out and leaves us no further forward, I have down-voted your answer. Your last para. also indicates confusion as to what the Son being God means when you speak of Jesus not being the Almighty, and not being Jehovah. The key in this verse is there only being one Saviour.

Comment: @Anne. The ultimate Savior is God. God accomplished this through the ransom sacrifice of Jesus.John 3:16. Who sent Jesus to save us? Jesus himself said the only true God sent him, John 17:3. If Jesus is the same God that sent him, Did Jesus send himself? Did God who is immortal die in order for us to be saved? How can you believe that Jesus is God and the only true God that sent Him also God without contradicting Jesus statement in John 17:3?

Comment: The defence of the bible and what it *actually* says, is often met with punitive voting. "forgive them for they know not what they do", comes to mind.  It's a tough gig, but someone's got to do it. +1 (I might have put all the sharp nonsense as an appendix to make it less confronting and quicker to get the point - the preceding verses are very telling)

Comment: Sharp did not invent a rule to promote Jesus is God. He simply took what is accepted throughout the New Testament and showed it applied in **all** cases. Ephesians 1:3 is an example: `εὐλογητὸς ὁ θεὸς καὶ πατὴρ` is a TSKS phrase *blessed be the God and Father* understood according to Sharp's Rule; showing God and Father apply to one. Sharp showed certain texts were improperly understood as the rule which is obvious in many places like Ephesians 1:3, was ignored when the text referred to Christ.